# Issues hosting angular application in Github Pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am attempting to host an angular app in github pages. I have gotten the site setup so the main page displays…but my main page requires an authorization redirect that forces my site to go the dashboard component. So I end up with a url like this: https://www.example.com/dashboard/#accessToken=someToken&bearer=someBearer

The problem is that on the redirect back to the dashboard component I get a “404 file not found”. It appears that this happens on any page I attempt to go to that is not the home page. I have been looking everywhere trying to find a solution to this but I can’t.

I have read about tracking the last visited page in session storage in order to redirect there through the index page but I was not able to get that to work. I have also attempted changing the base url set in the index page but that doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: Have you set `<base href="/">` in `<head>` tag on `index.html` page?

Comment: @Derek.W Yep. I currently have the base set that way and I still have the issue.

Comment: Do you use `HashLocationStrategy` or `PathLocationStrategy`? If you use `PathLocationStrategy`, pls try to move to `HashLocationStrategy` and try again.

Comment: @Derek.W I'm currently using PathLocationStrategy. I'll give it a shot and let you know what happens.

Comment: @Derek.W This solved my issue. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have added my answer. Can you have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location strategy is `PathLocationStrategy` in Angular projects.

There are 3 strategies in Angular (`PathLocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`, `MockLocationStrategy`) and you can know more details on [this link](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy).

If you are using `PathLocationStrategy`, pls change it to `HashLocationStrategy` and try again.
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your problem is [step 3](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages04.html.). So try this:

> When the build is complete, make a copy of docs/index.html and name it
> docs/404.html.

Make sure that there is a **404.html** file on your app root.